# How to make a parent div wrap (and shrink) its floating children?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive layout which consists of a bunch of  elements. Here is a very simplified version of the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/452nhsa9/1/)

What I am trying to achieve is making the header (yellow box) take the same width as the child divs (green boxes). And it works well when the layout is rendered at first, here is a screenshot from the JSFiddle
[image]

But when the screen size becomes more narrow the header doesn't shrink correctly, here is a screenshot for a smaller area:

[image]

I spent a few hours trying to figure it out, but I could not. Part of the challenge is that I don't know in advance what the number of green boxes is going to be as they are rendered dynamically by .NET

*Update 1*

The fact that the green boxes wrap is desired, what I'm trying to achieve is for the yellow box to have the same width as the combined width of the green boxes. Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Why couldn't you give the header a width of 100%?

Comment: @Hynes in the code above the header is set to the 100% width.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want with pure CSS. The dangling space is there because that's how much space is *left*. The box just goes below because there's no space above, you cannot shrink the yellow header because it does not "know" anything about the fact that green boxes do not fit. I tried a few hacks but couldn't get it to work. The safest bet is to go with JS.

However, here are some alternatives which you might find worth checking if you're flexible to change your design a bit.

## 1. Don't specify the size at all

You can let `flex-box` do its thing. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9cLhnfu/). Works with every number of elements, but they get too big or too small depending on the parent size and number of children.

## 2. Allow for space inbetween

`flex-box` to the rescue again, you can use `justify-content: space-between` to keep the header from the most-left box to most-right box correctly, but introduce space between. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edstub64/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. We'd need to keep the width of the green boxes fixed due to the nature of the content I'm afraid.

Comment: What exactly are you after then? They cannot stay in one line and be 100px wide if the parent is less than 100px times the number of boxes. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: No, sorry, the fact that they wrap is perfect. I just want the header (yellow box) to have the same width as the combined width of the green boxes. Let me update the question.

Comment: I see now. I don't think it's possible to do what you want with pure CSS. The dangling red space is there because that's how much space is _left_. The box just goes below because there's no space above, you cannot shrink the yellow header because it does not "know" anything about the fact that green boxes do not fit. I tried a few hacks but couldn't get it to work. The safest bet is to go with JS; although I'd love to see a solution with pure CSS.

Comment: Thank you, Lazar, I'm coming to the same conclusion as well. It is a bit annoying because of the first time it is rendered the yellow box has the correct width, so it knows the combined width of the green boxes at some point in time, but not when they start wrapping.

Comment: Been thinking for a while and couldn't get anywhere. Added another alternative you can try to see if it works for you, though.

Comment: Really awesome workaround. It probably won't work in my scenario I'm afraid. When two boxes wrap onto the next line one of them appears on the left and the other one on the right, but hopefully this workaround would be found useful by somebody else.